# How to use Eval function to validate an integer field & then show a text value?

Tags: asp.net, eval

I have this code :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("IsActive")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have to use Eval to validate IsActive field, which is of type INTEGER.
It can contain 1 or 0. By checking this value, I have to show to the user the output Yes or NO, because I don't want to show 1/0.
Can you please tell me how to do it ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
<%# (int)Eval("IsActive") == 1 ? "Yes" : "No" %>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is the same as Terence said, it works like sharm :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<% #Eval("IsActive") == 1 ? "Yes" : "No" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

if value is integer the lblsuccess will be shown. And if value is not integer then lblerror is shown. Place this code inside item template

```
<asp:Label id="lblsuccess" runat="server" Text="value is integer" 
Visible='<%# Int.TryParse("IntValue") ; %>' ></asp:Label>

<asp:Label id="lblerror" runat="server" Text="value is not integer" 
Visible='<%# !Int.TryParse("IntValue") ; %>' ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. TryParse requires an out, which is is anoying in front end code. Plus this does not clearly show how to use that with Eval